# How to inject all implementations of interface?

Tags: java, design-patterns, jakarta-ee

I have one interface (`First`) which I've implemented in two classes. Classes which implements the intereface I've annotated with `@Stateless` annotation, and interface is `@Remote`. Then i've created a `Main` interface with one method which should return `First` interface, it also annotated as `@Remote`. In implementation of `Main` int I've created an `Instance<First>`  field ,and annotated it with `@Inject` , and `Map<FirstType, First>` which I'm initializing in `setUp()` method with `@PostConstruct`. When i try to invoke `main.getFirst(FirstType.HELLO).getSomething()` it throws a NullpointerExeption. How to fix this issue.

```
@Remote
public interface First {

String getSomething();

FirstType getType();
}
```

_

```
@Stateless
public class ActionFirstImpl implements First {

@Override
public String getSomething() {

    return "Hello";
}
@Override
public FirstType getType() {
    return FirstType.ACTION;
}
```

_

```
@Remote
public interface TestWSFactory {

First getFirst(FirstType type);
}
```

_

```
@Stateless
public class TestWSFactoryImpl implements TestWSFactory {

@Inject
Instance<First> firstList;

private Map<FirstType, First> map;

@PostConstruct
void setUp() {
    map = new HashMap<>();

    firstList.forEach(t -> map.put(t.getType(), t));
}

@Override
public First getFirst(FirstType type) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(map.get(type)).orElse(null);
}
```

This pattern works perfectly with SpringBoot, but is it possible to do the same with jakarta-ee?

Comment: Did you already try it? The answer should be *yes*. Whereas you can inject a `List<First>` in Spring Boot, and using `@All` a `List<First>` in Quarkus, in Jave EE / Jakarta EE you're "stuck" with `Instance<First>`.

Comment: Unrelated, that implementation of `getFirst` is unnecessarily complex. Just return `map.get(type)`, instead of wrapping this in an `Optional` just to unwrap it again with `null` as fallback value.

Comment: @RobSpoor changed to map.get(type) but it still not working